# Calculate the UPS Capacity in amp-hours

Tags: homework-and-exercises, power, electric-current, batteries

I am trying to find out the [UPS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uninterruptible_power_supply) capacity in amp-hours for my HP UPS system.
I've already done some calculations based on the UPS information from the HP Power Manager software.

[image: HP UPS Parametars]

Bellow are my calculations but somehow I doubt them and I think I am making a mistake somewhere:

Output Power: **1160W**
Output Voltage: **235V**
Run time remaining: **12min** - Converted to hours that is **0.2h**

First I am converting the W to A:
1160W / 235V = **4.936A**

Now to find the amp-hours for 12min that are specified in the run time remaining:

**4.936A * 0.2h = 0.987Ah**

Can someone more experienced in batteries, current and UPS Systems tell me if my calculations are correct?

I am not sure that I have taken the correct values into consideration since **my calculations are based upon the output values from the UPS.**
Also as a side note I must tell you that I am not very fond of current and all that stuff and I have only basic knowledge about amps, volts and watts from college.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo that the Amperes output is 4.936, but that is corrected later on.  You also slipped a decimal when you did 4.936 * 0.2, which should give 0.9872.  The battery is at 130V, so the current out of the battery is $\frac {235}{130}\cdot 4.936=8.922$ and it is really a little higher for the losses in the conversion.  Let's say it is 9A out of the battery.  Then you would have 1.8 A-hr in the battery to run for 12 minutes.  I don't see where it says you can in fact run for an hour, so it looks to me like about 1.8 A-hr.  If you can run for an hour, it would be 9 A-hr.

Comment: Thanks Ross. I've corrected my calculations above. So I guess based on your calculations, I must first find the current out of the battery and then find the Amp-hours out of that current. This really helped me a lot :)